# error during the import of tensorflow-gpu version

Tags: python, tensorflow

> import tensorflow Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow   File "C:\Users\nayer meleka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 39, in 
>       from tensorflow._api.v1 import app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow._api'

[this error happend when I tried to import it from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaugB.png)

When I tried to use tensorflow this error pop up.

I installed it using pip didn't use any virtualmachine.

Comment: please edit to explain how did you installed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing tensorflow-gpu again by running the command prompt in *administrator mode* still through pip. And keep in mind that it won't just start using the GPU by itself, you will have to install other dependencies too such as **Visual Studio, CUDA, CUDNN**, etc.

Read this: https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu

Comment: thanks that guide was really helpful and it works :D turns out i was doing something wrong with adding environmental variables :D

Comment: That's great, glad I could help!